# forced directed graphs using d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I have started using the d3.js library for making forced directed graphs. Could somebody tell me why this code also mentioned in [this site](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) does not work?

**index.html**

```
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>
```

**miserables.json**

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
    {"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
    {"name":"Geborand","group":1},
    {"name":"Champtercier","group":1},
    {"name":"Cravatte","group":1},
    {"name":"Count","group":1},
    {"name":"OldMan","group":1},
    {"name":"Labarre","group":2},
    {"name":"Valjean","group":2},
    {"name":"Marguerite","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.deR","group":2},
    {"name":"Isabeau","group":2},
    {"name":"Gervais","group":2},
    {"name":"Tholomyes","group":3},
    {"name":"Listolier","group":3},
    {"name":"Fameuil","group":3},
    {"name":"Blacheville","group":3},
    {"name":"Favourite","group":3},
    {"name":"Dahlia","group":3},
    {"name":"Zephine","group":3},
    {"name":"Fantine","group":3},
    {"name":"Mme.Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Thenardier","group":4},
    {"name":"Cosette","group":5},
    {"name":"Javert","group":4},
    {"name":"Fauchelevent","group":0},
    {"name":"Bamatabois","group":2},
    {"name":"Perpetue","group":3},
    {"name":"Simplice","group":2},
    {"name":"Scaufflaire","group":2},
    {"name":"Woman1","group":2},
    {"name":"Judge","group":2},
    {"name":"Champmathieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Brevet","group":2},
    {"name":"Chenildieu","group":2},
    {"name":"Cochepaille","group":2},
    {"name":"Pontmercy","group":4},
    {"name":"Boulatruelle","group":6},
    {"name":"Eponine","group":4},
    {"name":"Anzelma","group":4},
    {"name":"Woman2","group":5},
    {"name":"MotherInnocent","group":0},
    {"name":"Gribier","group":0},
    {"name":"Jondrette","group":7},
    {"name":"Mme.Burgon","group":7},
    {"name":"Gavroche","group":8},
    {"name":"Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Magnon","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Mme.Pontmercy","group":5},
    {"name":"Mlle.Vaubois","group":5},
    {"name":"Lt.Gillenormand","group":5},
    {"name":"Marius","group":8},
    {"name":"BaronessT","group":5},
    {"name":"Mabeuf","group":8},
    {"name":"Enjolras","group":8},
    {"name":"Combeferre","group":8},
    {"name":"Prouvaire","group":8},
    {"name":"Feuilly","group":8},
    {"name":"Courfeyrac","group":8},
    {"name":"Bahorel","group":8},
    {"name":"Bossuet","group":8},
    {"name":"Joly","group":8},
    {"name":"Grantaire","group":8},
    {"name":"MotherPlutarch","group":9},
    {"name":"Gueulemer","group":4},
    {"name":"Babet","group":4},
    {"name":"Claquesous","group":4},
    {"name":"Montparnasse","group":4},
    {"name":"Toussaint","group":5},
    {"name":"Child1","group":10},
    {"name":"Child2","group":10},
    {"name":"Brujon","group":4},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
    {"source":9,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":10,"value":1},
    {"source":11,"target":3,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":2,"value":3},
    {"source":11,"target":0,"value":5},
    {"source":12,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":13,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":14,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":15,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":17,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":18,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":16,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":17,"value":4},
    {"source":19,"target":18,"value":4},
    {"source":20,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":20,"target":19,"value":4},
    {"source":21,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":21,"target":20,"value":5},
    {"source":22,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":22,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":22,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":16,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":17,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":18,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":19,"value":3},
    {"source":23,"target":20,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":21,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":22,"value":4},
    {"source":23,"target":12,"value":2},
    {"source":23,"target":11,"value":9},
    {"source":24,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":24,"target":11,"value":7},
    {"source":25,"target":24,"value":13},
    {"source":25,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":25,"target":11,"value":12},
    {"source":26,"target":24,"value":4},
    {"source":26,"target":11,"value":31},
    {"source":26,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":26,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":11,"value":17},
    {"source":27,"target":23,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":27,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":27,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":28,"target":11,"value":8},
    {"source":28,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":29,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":30,"target":23,"value":1},
    {"source":31,"target":30,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":31,"target":23,"value":2},
    {"source":31,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":32,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":33,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":33,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":34,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":34,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":35,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":34,"value":3},
    {"source":35,"target":29,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":36,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":37,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":37,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":38,"target":34,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":35,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":36,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":37,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":38,"target":29,"value":1},
    {"source":39,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":40,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":41,"target":24,"value":2},
    {"source":41,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":42,"target":41,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":42,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":11,"value":3},
    {"source":43,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":43,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":44,"target":28,"value":3},
    {"source":44,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":45,"target":28,"value":2},
    {"source":47,"target":46,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":47,"value":2},
    {"source":48,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":48,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":49,"target":26,"value":3},
    {"source":49,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":50,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":50,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":51,"target":49,"value":9},
    {"source":51,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":51,"target":11,"value":2},
    {"source":52,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":52,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":53,"target":51,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":51,"value":2},
    {"source":54,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":54,"target":26,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":51,"value":6},
    {"source":55,"target":49,"value":12},
    {"source":55,"target":39,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":54,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":26,"value":21},
    {"source":55,"target":11,"value":19},
    {"source":55,"target":16,"value":1},
    {"source":55,"target":25,"value":2},
    {"source":55,"target":41,"value":5},
    {"source":55,"target":48,"value":4},
    {"source":56,"target":49,"value":1},
    {"source":56,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":57,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":55,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":58,"target":27,"value":6},
    {"source":58,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":58,"target":11,"value":4},
    {"source":59,"target":58,"value":15},
    {"source":59,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":59,"target":48,"value":6},
    {"source":59,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":60,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":60,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":60,"target":59,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":58,"value":6},
    {"source":61,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":61,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":61,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":61,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":55,"value":9},
    {"source":62,"target":58,"value":17},
    {"source":62,"target":59,"value":13},
    {"source":62,"target":48,"value":7},
    {"source":62,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":62,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":62,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":62,"target":60,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":63,"target":62,"value":6},
    {"source":63,"target":57,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":58,"value":4},
    {"source":63,"target":61,"value":3},
    {"source":63,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":63,"target":55,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":55,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":62,"value":12},
    {"source":64,"target":48,"value":5},
    {"source":64,"target":63,"value":4},
    {"source":64,"target":58,"value":10},
    {"source":64,"target":61,"value":6},
    {"source":64,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":64,"target":59,"value":9},
    {"source":64,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":64,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":63,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":64,"value":7},
    {"source":65,"target":48,"value":3},
    {"source":65,"target":62,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":58,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":61,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":60,"value":2},
    {"source":65,"target":59,"value":5},
    {"source":65,"target":57,"value":1},
    {"source":65,"target":55,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":64,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":58,"value":3},
    {"source":66,"target":59,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":62,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":65,"value":2},
    {"source":66,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":61,"value":1},
    {"source":66,"target":60,"value":1},
    {"source":67,"target":57,"value":3},
    {"source":68,"target":25,"value":5},
    {"source":68,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":68,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":25,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":68,"value":6},
    {"source":69,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":27,"value":2},
    {"source":69,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":69,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":25,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":69,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":68,"value":4},
    {"source":70,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":24,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":70,"target":58,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":69,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":68,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":70,"value":2},
    {"source":71,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":71,"target":25,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":26,"value":2},
    {"source":72,"target":27,"value":1},
    {"source":72,"target":11,"value":1},
    {"source":73,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":48,"value":2},
    {"source":74,"target":73,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":69,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":68,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":25,"value":3},
    {"source":75,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":41,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":70,"value":1},
    {"source":75,"target":71,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":64,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":65,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":66,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":63,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":62,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you just want some debug, for which this site is not about, at least post a jsFiddle so we can try to do the debugging for zou.

Comment: I have been long enough in SO, but this was an emergency and I have very little idea of javascript. Generally I would some research of my own before asking here.

Comment: No worries, your question was in fact interesting given the fact that it is hard to see why the same code didn't work locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you provided works, as you can see on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/g6Ujg/). The only difference is that I didn't use the `d3.json` function to load the json file.

The problem you have is certainly that you want to run it locally, and that the json is not loaded. You need to run a server on your computer to make it work. Here is a question that can also help: [d3.json: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715891/d3-json-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-children-of-undefined)

The simplest way to have a local web server, as explained [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) is to run this command in the directory where you have your source code:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

Then just load the page `http://localhost:8888`