# "TypeError: root.children is undefined" on Collapsible Tree d3 v3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying one of Mike Bostock's [collapsible tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) examples with d3 v3. However, I always receive the following error:

> TypeError: root_03.children is undefined

I have referred to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715891/d3-json-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-children-of-undefined) for troubleshooting but the solutions do not work.

Does anyone have the answer to this? Or could it be because this code does not work at v3 anymore?

Here is my JS code:

```
var w_canvas_03 = 960;
var h_canvas_03 = 800;

var margin_03 = {
    top: 50,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
};

var w_chart_03 = w_canvas_03 - margin_03.left - margin_03.right;
var h_chart_03 = h_canvas_03 - margin_03.top - margin_03.bottom;

var i_03 = 0;
var duration_03 = 750;
var root_03;

var tree_03 = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([h_chart_03, w_chart_03]);

var diagonal_03 = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(data_){
                return [data_.y, data_.x];
            });

var svg_03 = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w_canvas_03)
            .attr("height", h_canvas_03)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_03.left + "," + margin_03.top + ")");

d3.json("resource/json_remark.json", function(error_, source_){
    if (error_) throw error_;
    root_03 = source_;
    root_03.x0 = h_chart_03 / 2;
    root_03.y0 = 0;
    console.log(root_03)

    function Collapse_03(data_){
        if (data_.children){
            data_._children = data_.children;
            data_._children.forEach(Collapse_03);
            data_.children = null;
        }
    }

    root_03.children.forEach(Collapse_03);
    Update_03(root_03);
})

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", h_canvas_03);

function Update_03(source_){

    // Computing the flattened node list
    var nodeAll_03 = tree_03.nodes(root_03).reverse()
    var linkAll_03 = tree_03.links(nodeAll_03);

    // Normalizing for fixed-depth
    nodeAll_03.forEach(function(data_){
        data_.y = 180 * data_.depth;
    });


    // Updating the node
    var node_03 = svg_03.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodeAll_03, function(data_){
            return data_.id || (data_.id = ++i_03);
        });

    var nodeEnter_03 = node_03.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(data_){
            return "translate(" + source_.y0 + "," + source_.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on("click", Click_03);

    // Entering any new nodes at the parent's previous position
    nodeEnter_03.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(data_){
            data_._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"
;       });

    nodeEnter_03.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(data_){
            data_.children || data_.children ? -10:10;
        })
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(data_){
            return data_.children || data_.children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(data_){
            return data_.name;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transitioning nodes to their new position
    var nodeUpdate_03 = node_03.transition()
        .duration(duration_03)
        .attr("transform", function(data_){
            return "translate(" + data_.y + "," + data_.x + ")";
        });

    nodeUpdate_03.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function(data_){
            return data_._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff;"
        });

    nodeUpdate_03.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transitioning exiting nodes to the parent's new position
    var nodeExit_03 = node_03.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration_03)
        .attr("transform", function(data_){
            return "translate(" + source_.y + "," + source_.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

    nodeExit_03.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit_03.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Updating the links
    var link_03 = svg_03.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(linkAll_03, function(data_){
            return data_.target.id;
        });

    // Entering any new links at the parent's previous position
    link_03.enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(data_){
            var o_03 = {x: source_.x0, y: source_.y0};
            return diagonal_03({source: o_03, target: o_03});
        });

    // Transitioning links to their new position
    link_03.transition()
        .duration(duration_03)
        .attr("d", diagonal_03);

    // Transitioning exiting nodes to the parent's new position
    link_03.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(duration_03)
        .attr("d", function(data_){
            var o_03 = {x: source_.x, y: source_.y};
            return diagonal_03({source: o_03, target: o_03});
        })
        .remove();

    // Stashing the old positions for transition
    nodeAll_03.forEach(function(data_){
        data_.x0 = data_.x;
        data_.y0 = data_.y;
    });

}

// Toggling children on click
function Click_03(data_){
    if (data_.children){
        data_._children = data_.children;
        data_.children = null;
    } else{
        data_.children = data_._children;
        data_._children = null;
    }
    Update_03(data_)
}
```

And here is the simplified version of my JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Neutral",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Fruit",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Apple"
          },
          {
            "name": "Orange"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the original Bostock's bl.ocks you'll see that its JSON (`"flare.json"`) file has an **object**, not an array. However, your JSON file has an **array** (with a single object inside it).

Therefore, the solution is simple:

```
root_03 = source_[0];
//1st element-----^
```

This get's the first element of that array, which is the root object with the `children` property.

Here is a bl.ocks with your code: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/ae2bcac26194865317d0ec6b55361221/070902f5daaf9d90f061455d11d04769439a8b4c

Comment: It works! Didn't realize that the issue lies on the JSON file. Really appreciate your help.